# How to handle Tap event from Hold Event in WindowsPhone8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, user-controls

I have a usercontrol and tap event which is in usercontrol itself..And am having holding event for that usercontrol in phoneapplication page which is parent page.I want to raise tap event from hold event how do i achieve this?..
ParentPage is having:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template" >
    <chatbubble:ChatBubbleControl x:Name="ChatBubble" Hold="ChatBubbleControl_Hold_1" />  
</DataTemplate>
```

UserControl is having..

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    ....
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Width="455" Tap="chatBubble_Tap" >
    .....
   </Grid>
```

I want to raise chatBubble_Tap event from ChatBubbleControl_Hold_1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to raise your event like this:

```
// make your eventhandler in Parent Page public and static so it will be available thru all the App
public static void chatBubble_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}

// then in your UserControl you should be able to call it like this:
private void ChatBubbleControl_Hold_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    YourPage.chatBubble_Tap(sender, e);
}
```

This case depends on what you have in your Tap event (not everything can be in static method).

You can also pass the handler of your Page to your UserControl and then invoke your Tap event from handler (in this case the Tap event can be `public` (non-static). Simple case can look like this:

```
// your Control in MainPage (or other Page)
<local:myControl x:Name="yourControl" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>

// initializing control and event to be invoked:
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    yourControl.pageHandler = this;
}

public void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // something here
}

// and the control code:
public partial class myControl : UserControl
{
    public Page pageHandler;

    public myControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myButton.Hold +=myButton_Hold;
    }

    private void myButton_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pageHandler is MainPage) (pageHandler as MainPage).second_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

The third option would be to pass an `Action` to your Control (in this case event can be private):

```
// code in MainPage (or your Page)
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    yourControl.myAction = second_Click; // setting an action of Control
}

private void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // something here
}

// and the Control class
public partial class myControl : UserControl
{
    public Action<object, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs> myAction;

    public myControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myButton.Hold +=myButton_Hold;
    }

    private void myButton_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myAction != null) myAction.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```